# Setting longitude and latitude range for mapbox map

Tags: python, mapbox

I am trying to mark some points on a map. But I would like to zoom in automatically. So I use the following code which works perfectly fine for go.Scattergeo plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

margin = 0.002

fig.update_layout(
    title = 'Something',
    autosize=False,
    width=800,
    height=600,
    geo = dict(
        # projection_scale=8000, #this is kind of like zoom
        lonaxis = dict(
            range= [ df['longitude'].min()-margin, df['longitude'].max()+margin ],
            dtick = 5
        ),
        lataxis = dict (
            range= [ df['latitude'].min()-margin, df['latitude'].max()+margin ],
            dtick = 5
        )
    )
)
```

But when change the plot to mapbox, the lataxis and lonaxis seem not working anymore.

```
# fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, 
#                         lat="latitude", 
#                         lon="longitude", 
#                         color="rssi",
#                         color_continuous_scale=px.colors.cyclical.IceFire)
fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        lon = df['longitude'],
        lat = df['latitude'],
        mode = 'markers',
        marker = dict(
                autocolorscale = False,
                colorscale = 'icefire',
                color = df['rssi'],
        )))

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
```

Any idea how can make it work? Or how can zoom in and center graph? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I see that the ability to limit latitude and longitude is a content in `px.scatter_maxbox()`. I think the only way to adjust it is to use the center point of the latitude and longitude to be displayed and the zoom.

Comment: How to do that in `px.scatter_maxbox()`

Comment: For example, the code will look something like this. `px.scatter_mapbox(..., center=dict(lon=12.45, lat=41.95), zoom=5)`

Comment: Then the zoom factor is not perfect. Is there a formula that I can calculate zoom factors to get the same result?